# ios swift Hide UINavigationBar created by NavigationViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have several views in my storyboard. 
The flow of the program is a user enters start mileage in my MileageViewController (which is a standard UIViewController) and then clicks a button to select their start location from a separate view. This view is a treeviewcontroller and because of editing I had to embed in a NavigationViewController which introduced a UINavigationBar and I have an edit button. I can edit my list (and I'll eventually add adding to the list).

All is fine... until I segue from a cell in the treeview back to my MileageViewController into which I update the title from the selected cell into startLocation UIText... hope I've painted a picture you understand... :)

My problem is that on getting back to the MileageViewController it now has a header (UINavigationBar) with Back to LocationChoiceTreeViewController.... how do I disable the header in this instance?

Comment: do you want to remove the whole bar so the viewController is "Full screen" or just remove the back button ?

Comment: remove the whole bar please... note it's not there the first time the user sees the MileageViewController... it only appears after they return from the LocationChoiceTreeViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the viewWillAppear of the controller

```
if let n = navigationController {
    n.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```